# How to write a Ruby gem that can be invoked without the word 'ruby' preceding it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to write a CLI application wrapped into a Gem that can be invoked the same way git commands are invoked, or gem commands. Eg when running say "git clone " you don't need to precede it with 'ruby'. However, the tutorials and articles I've seen so far about writing gems, don't show this. The examples either require you to run your gem through irb, with appropriate requires, or you run it like 'ruby '. This is not what I want. If you know of any tutorials that cover this, then that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Comment: I've already read that tutorial and it doesn't cover the issue I'm talking about. In that example it's still executing the gem with 'ruby' on the command line. That article only talks about putting a ruby script in the bin directory and making it executable.

Comment: The shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`) at the start of the script is the magic; when the script is executable, you can invoke it directly and the shebang tells it which executable to execute the script with.

Comment: the tutorial is not as clear as it could be, but they are only executing the gem with `ruby` on the command line in development. It does correctly outline the way to make a ruby gem that will provide an exectuable script you can execute by itself, once you've installed the gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "#!" line at the start of a script tells your shell which executable to execute the script with. In this case, it tells it to find the Ruby executable from the environment and give the script to it for execution.

By means of example, I have a file called "hi", with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "hi!"
```

I make it executable:

```
$ chmod a+x hi
```

Then I can execute it directly, without explicitly invoking the Ruby interpreter:

```
$ ./hi
hi!
```

Per [the tutuorial](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) you would simply provide such a file which requires your gem and whatnot, and provide it in the `executables` property of your gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.executables << 'hi'
```

When the gem is installed, the `hi` script would be installed into a location discoverable on the path, so you could then invoke it.

Comment: Ok thanks, your explanation of this point is better than the tutorial. The tutorial still goes on about ruby ..., which is why I didnt think it hit the spot. Thanks.